# ¿Cómo usar una store desde otra en Pinia (Vue 3)?

Tags: vue3, pinia

Estoy creando un par de stores con vue 3, una de ellas (user.js) contiene la siguiente estructura:

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import { useGlobalStore } from './global.js';

// Esta línea me arroja el error
const globalStore = useGlobalStore();

export const useUserStore = defineStore('user', {
    state: () => {
        return {
            formCreate: {
                name: '',
                age: '',
                job: ''
            },
            validations: {
                name: globalStore.validations.hasUpperCase,
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Esto me arroja el error:

**Uncaught Error: []: getActivePinia was called with no active Pinia. Did you forget to install pinia?
const pinia = createPinia()
app.use(pinia)**

Allí donde lo indico, resulta que estoy importando otra store llamada `global.js`, la cual tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';

export const useGlobalStore = defineStore('global', {
    state: () => {
        return {
            validations: {
                hasUpperCase: value => /[A-Z]/.test(value),
            },
        }
    }
});
```

Ya realicé lo que indica el error, importar pinia desde la creación de la app en `app.js`:

```
//...
import { createPinia } from 'pinia';
const pinia = createPinia();

//...
createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
    .use(pinia)
    .mount(el);
```

Sé claramente que el problema no es sobre instalación o instancia de pinia, ya que intenté usar tanto `user.js` y `global.js` de manera independiente desde mis componentes de Vue y funcionan ambos correctamente, el problema es que no puedo acceder entre stores. ¿Habrá alguna solución?

Answer (score 0):

No debe declararse fuera de la instancia donde importa: Son únicas, es decir, al exportar `useGlobalStore`  que usa `defineStore` crea conflicto porque no sabe cual es la correcta.

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import { useGlobalStore } from './global.js';

export const useUserStore = defineStore('user', {
  state: () => ({
    formCreate: {
      name: '',
      age: '',
      job: '',
      hash:'', //{}, [], ...
    }
  }),
  /* Es mejor usar getter para extraer el hash y asignarlo al estado:
     (No debe depender el estado del store de instancias de otro por reactividad)*/
  getters: {
    hash: () => useGlobalStore().validations.hasUpperCase
  }
});
```